# how to take 2 .txt files and plot them on a graph using python?

Tags: python, csv, numpy, matplotlib, conda

I'm trying to figure out how to take two text files filled with comma-seperated values and find their point average. Here's roughly my values that I have from my two files:

file 1

```
1,24.5

2,24.2

3,27.3

.....

50,25.2
```

file 2

```
1,23.4

2,23.4

3,18.9

.....

50,27.0
```

And my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x, y = np.loadtxt('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\data\\input_temperature1.txt', delimiter=',', unpack=True)
plt.plot(x,y, color='Blue', label='Input temperature 1')

x, y = np.loadtxt('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\data\\input_temperature2.txt', delimiter=',', unpack=True)
plt.plot(x,y,color='Red', label='Input temperature 2')

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Temperature Comparioson Plot')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I have no clue where to go from here or what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If this question is about finding the average of two arrays, all the matplotlib plotting is irrelevant and you should remove it.

Comment: I have to find the average of every value in the y1 and y2 and plot them on the same graph, not the total average of the whole thing.

Comment: Yes, see my solution below on how to do that. My point here is that finding an average is independent of plotting and you seem to know how to plot an array in matplotlib, so you can get rid of everything that has to do with matplotlib in the question.

Comment: thank you for your help but how to i only take the second comma and get the average from that for both files and run them on the same graph?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *second comma*. But I edited my answer such that there is the full code that you'd need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finding the average of two arrays `y` and `y2` in numpy can be done with  [`numpy.mean()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) as follows. You can concatenate the two arrays and calculate the mean along the column-axis.

```
average = numpy.column_stack((y,y2)).mean(axis=1)
```

In total your code may look like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x1, y1 = np.loadtxt('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\data\\input_temperature1.txt', delimiter=',', unpack=True)
plt.plot(x1,y1, color='Blue', label='Input temperature 1')

x2, y2 = np.loadtxt('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\data\\input_temperature2.txt', delimiter=',', unpack=True)
plt.plot(x2,y2,color='Red', label='Input temperature 2')

average = numpy.column_stack((y1,y2)).mean(axis=1)
plt.plot(x2,average,color='green', label='Average Temperature')

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Temperature Comparison Plot')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: sorry for any confusion and thank you for answering my question you are a life saver